# WinRT hierarchical data displaying

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, hierarchical

I need to display hierarchical data like:

```cs
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Element[] Elements { get; private set; }
}
```

It would be just vertical panel with rectangle (with `Name`) for each element. If element is clicked, its child elements are displayed below it (element is expanded). If one of them is clicked, its elements appear and so on.

I already googled this and found out that there is no HierarchicalDataTemplate and no treeview in WinRT.
So I started to do it by myself.
I created `ItemsControl` and `DataTemplate` `DataTemplate1` for it. In `DataTemplate1` I also create `ItemsControl` and set `DataTemplate2` as `ItemTemplate`. In `DataTemplate2`, `ItemTemplate` is `DataTemplate3` and so on. The last `DataTemplate` is without `ItemsControl`.

In buttons `Click` event I change Elements `IsVisible` property for any elements in `DataModel` (that is `Element[]`), so it is easy to perform any custom logic to expand/collapse elements.

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Button  Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}"
                 Click="MenuElement_Click">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Button>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate3}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <Button  Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}"
                 Click="MenuElement_Click">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Button>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

It works fine, but the problem is that if I want to enable 10 levels of hierarchy, I have to copypast 10 datatemplates. And 11 level still will not be available.

I also tried to create `DataTemplate` in C# and manually apply `DataTemplate` for its `ItemSource` and so on, in recursive method.
But I found 2 problems.

1. I don't know actually how to create `DataTemplate` in metro (C#), because it has no `VisualTree` property. I can only make (`var dt= new Datatemplate();`) and I don't know how to change it.
2. If I read `DataTemplate` from XAML (`var dateTemplateRoot = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DataTemplate1"];`)

I still can't find `ItemsControl` in it and change its `DataTemplate`.
Actually, I can use `var content = dateTemplateRoot.LoadContent();` and then find `ItemsControl` by `VisualTreeHelper`, but I can't use content after that as `DataTemplate` (content has type `DependencyObject`).

So, actually I have 2 questions.
Is it a good approach to perform hierarchical dropdown list by "binding" all items and only switch `Visibility` property?
The second is - how to enable unlimited level of hierarchical nesting?

Comment: Have a look at the Silverlight toolkit for Silverlight 3 - there was no HierarchicalDataTemplate in SL3 but the toolkit provided one, and a TreeView.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has a `TreeView` control now. Check it out: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b0ee76bd6492#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs

Take care though - this is just a rough port from Silverlight Toolkit and might not work so well. Also if you are planning on releasing it as part of a Windows Store application - you would need to heavily restyle it unless your app is desktop-only since it is not very touch-friendly.